# CMake finding incorrect version of OpenCV

Tags: macos, cmake, opencv3.0

I have multiple versions of OpenCV installed, and CMake is finding the wrong one. I have installed opencv and opencv3 using brew, and they exist in the following paths:

```
/usr/local/opt/opencv3
/usr/local/opt/opencv
```

My CMakeLists.txt looks like the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(ENV{OpenCV_DIR} "/usr/local/opt/opencv3")

project(TestProject)

#OpenCV
find_package( OpenCV 3 REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

MESSAGE ( STATUS "Found OpenCV: ${OpenCV_VERSION}" )
MESSAGE ( STATUS "OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS= ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}" )
MESSAGE ( STATUS "OpenCV_DIR= $ENV{OpenCV_DIR}" )
```

I am using OpenCV_DIR to point to the location of the OpenCV that I would like to use (in this example it's set immediately before just to be 100% certain that this variable points to the right place).

My output is this:

```
-- Found OpenCV: 3.0.0
-- OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS= /usr/local/include/opencv
-- OpenCV_DIR= /usr/local/opt/opencv3
```

So, it's finding the right version of OpenCV (3.0.0), but the include path is set to some other opencv, in this case /usr/local/include/opencv points to /usr/local/opt/opencv, which is the 2.4.8 version.

As a result, none of my programs find the right files to include! Does anyone know how to tell CMake which version to look for, if the OpenCV_DIR environment variable does not seem to work?

Comment: `the OpenCV_DIR environment variable does not seem to work` - you need to use **Cmake** variable, not *environment* one. Just remove `ENV`.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either. OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS remains the same. Thanks,

Comment: Did you clean build dir (at least, cache) before new attempt?

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly assign the path in `find_package`. For example,

`find_package( OpenCV 3 REQUIRED PATHS "/usr/local/opt/opencv3" )`

Answer (score 1):

As indicated OP is using cMake V2.8. Therefore the following applies to include your desired directory.

```py
#OpenCV
find_package( OpenCV 3 REQUIRED )
include_directories([BEFORE] "/usr/local/opt/opencv3")  # your cv2 desired folder
                                                        #            stated here.
```

The `[BEFORE]` argument informs cMake about this particular folder to use first rather than the other CV folder.

For cMake higher than v2.8 you should **not** use the `include_directories` but rather the following:

`target_include_directories(test PRIVATE ${YOUR_DIRECTORY})`